# Legal website to practice using hydra

Tags: hydra

I am trying to learn how to use hydra to crack login passwords.

Does anybody know a legal website I can crack and if so the information needed or the code needed to enter the form into hydra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous options. VMs designed to be hacked (DVWA, metasploitable, etc.), hacking websites where attacks are permitted, or creating your own service.

But don't overlook the obvious: your own router. The login web page is simple, and you know the password. Give it a shot.

Comment: It's also fun to password-protect something but randomize something about it, so you get a feeling for the difference between perfect secrecy and leaking metadata.